# EntityFieldQuery fieldCondition

Tags: 7, entities, database

I have the following code:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$result = $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'field_collection_item', '=')
    ->propertyCondition('field_name', 'field_version', '=')
    ->fieldCondition('field_version', 'entity_id', '105', '=')
    ->execute()
;
```

The first two conditions are fine, but the fieldCondition() is causing the following SQL exception:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_data_field_version0.field_version_entity_id' in 'where clause'...

The problem seems to be that 'field_version' is prepended to the column 'entity_id'.  I have looked inside `_field_sql_storage_query_field_conditions()` and there appears to be no way to stop it from prepending this. This is the table I am trying to perform the fieldCondition on:

```
+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------------+    
| entity_type | bundle        | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | language | delta | field_version_value |    
+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------------+
| node        | shopping_cart |       0 |       105 |         123 | und      | 0     |                   5 |
| node        | shopping_cart |       0 |       108 |         126 | und      | 0     |                   8 |
+-------------+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

How may I perform this query correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this a different way.

I was trying to retrieve the entity ID in order to retrieve the information from the node that the field collection was attached to.  Instead, however, I used `node_load()` to load the relevant nodes.  I then was able to retrieve the entity ID of the field collection object and load it using `entity_load()`.

Comment: If that's what you want, then this is the correct way and EntityField does not help you. What EntityFieldQuery does is load entity ids of entities based on their properties and fields. You could for example use it if you want to load the node(s) that has a specific version value by first loading the field collection item and then loading the node that references the field collection item. You're doing the opposite, you have the node and want the version value. To get field values, you always need to load the entities.

Answer (score 2):

`entity_id` is the entity ID of the entity the field is attached to; in this case, the ID of your field collection item. To add a condition on that, you need to use a `propertyCondition()` on the "field_collection_item" primary key.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I have added this to the code block above: `->propertyCondition('entity_id', '105', '=')` but this gives me `Unknown column 'field_collection_item.entity_id' in 'where clause`.  In other words, it's trying to run the condition on the `field_collection_item` table when I want to be running the clause on the `field_data_field_version` table.  Please could you expand?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still intrested in this one, it can be done via:

`->entityCondition('entity_id', '68', '!=')`