# EntityFieldQuery for retrieve only 1 field

Tags: 7, database

I'm developing a new rules action that it is called by EntityForm when a Form is submitted.

In this action I want to retrieve 1 field from "noleggiatori" content type, so this is my function:

```
function zbl_rules_send_email_to_noleggiatori($entityForm) {

  $prov = $entityForm->field_provincia[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];
  $reg = $entityForm->field_regione[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];

  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'noleggiatori')
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
        ->fieldCondition('field_provincia', 'tid', $prov, '=')
        ->fieldCondition('field_regione', 'tid', $reg, '=')
        ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

  $result = $query->execute(); 
  dd($result);

  $articles = $result['node'];
  $fields = field_info_instances('node', 'noleggiatori');
  $field_id = $fields['field_email_per_comunicazoini']['field_id'];
  field_attach_load('node', $articles, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));  
  dd("articles");
  dd($articles);

  /* Other lines .... */
}
```

But I have a problem: the code is correct (no error), but it does not work correctly because it set ALL content type's fields in `$articles`. I want only "field_email_per_comunicazioni". Is this possible? How?

Comment: Have you tried a more D6 way with node_load() [EntityFieldQuery fieldCondition](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29114/entityfieldquery-fieldcondition)

Answer (score 3):

The code looks correct. Note that according to the [field_attach_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7) documentation:

> The field ID that should be loaded, instead of loading all fields, for each entity. Note that returned entities may contain data for other fields, for example if they are read from a cache.

So having other fields than field_email_per_comunicazioni does not mean the code does not work properly.